# PHP-CPP Include arquivo dentro da extensão

Tags: include, extensão, php-cpp

Estou desenvolvendo uma extensão php com PHP-CPP, onde eu preciso fazer um include de um arquivo php dentro da extensão, estou fazendo isso para proteger o código. Estou tentando deste modo:

```
Php::Value HomeController () {
std::string source = "";
source += "<?php\r\n";
source += "namespace App\\Http\\Controllers\\ajax;\r\n";
source += "use Illuminate\\Http\\Request;\r\n";
source += "use App\\Http\\Requests;\r\n";
source += "use App\\Http\\Controllers\\Controller;\r\n";
source += "class HorarioController extends Controller {\r\n";
source += "protected $page = \"ajax.horario\";\r\n";
source += "public function index(){\r\n";
source += "return $this->view;\r\n";
source += "}\r\n";
source += "}\r\n";

Php::Value val = Php::call("base64_encode", source);
std::string retorno = val;
retorno = "data://text/plain;base64,"+retorno;

return retorno;
}
```

mas se a pessoa remover o "data://text/plain;base64," e usar o base64_decode tem acesso a minha classe. 
Tentei deste modo também:

```
void HomeControllerInclude () {
std::string source = "";
source += "<?php\r\n";
source += "namespace App\\Http\\Controllers\\ajax;\r\n";
source += "use Illuminate\\Http\\Request;\r\n";
source += "use App\\Http\\Requests;\r\n";
source += "use App\\Http\\Controllers\\Controller;\r\n";
source += "class HorarioController extends Controller {\r\n";
source += "protected $page = \"ajax.horario\";\r\n";
source += "public function index(){\r\n";
source += "return $this->view;\r\n";
source += "}\r\n";
source += "}\r\n";

Php::Value val = Php::call("base64_encode", source);
std::string retorno = val;
retorno = "data://text/plain;base64,"+retorno;

Php::call("include", retorno);
}
```

Mas recebo o seguinte erro: `Invalid call to include`

Observação: Estou utilizando este método pois é o mais seguro que conheço, os demais possuem dezenas de métodos para fazer engenharia inversa.

EDIÇÃO:
Acabei achando uma função no PHP-CPP que faz o include, é a função `Php::include()` ela funciona perfeitamente com arquivos php, mas quando eu tendo utilizar o include com o `data://text/plain;base64,` não recebo nem uma mensagem de erro e não faz o include, o que será?

```
Php::Value HomeControllerInclude () {
    std::string source = "";


    source = "<?php class novo { public static function coco() {  return 20; } }";

    Php::Value val = Php::call("base64_encode", source);
    std::string retorno = val;

    retorno = "data://text/plain;base64,"+retorno;


    return include(retorno);
}
```

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza, mas acho que o erro ocorre porque `include` não é uma função e sim um "language-construct" do PHP.

Comment: Verdade, acabei achando uma função do PHP-CPP que faz o include, mas acabei me deparando com um problema, vou editar a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Php::include` é usado apenas pra incluir arquivos reais e provavelmente não suporta o protocolo `data:` que geralmente (se não unicamente) usado pra aplicações html.

Note que no [github](https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/PHP-CPP/blob/master/zend/eval.cpp#L46) o metodo include tenta ler um arquivo:

```
Value include(const char *filename)
{
    // we can simply execute a file
    return File(filename).execute();
}
```

O correto provavelmente seria usar `Php::eval`, veja como é o source dele:

```
Value eval(const char *phpCode) 
{
    // we have a script for this
    return Script(phpCode).execute();
}
```

O código deve ficar algo como:

```
Php::Value HomeControllerInclude () {
    std::string source = "";

    source = "<?php class novo { public static function coco() {  return 20; } }";

    return eval(source);
}
```

Ou:

```
return Php::eval(source);
```

Pode ocorrer do `<?php` afetar o `eval`, então use assim:

```
return eval("?>" + source);
```

Comment: Fiz exatamente como me mostras, mas recebo a mensagem: PHP Parse error:  parse error in Unknown on line 1

Comment: Resolvi o problema, removi o <?php e executou tranquilamente.

Comment: @PedroSoares isto não tem haver com o que eu fiz e sim com a tua string. Corrija ela e resolverá.

Comment: @PedroSoares tente assim também e me diga o que acontece `return eval("?>" + source);`

Comment: Também funcionou. Muito obrigado, me ajudou muito.